# React.js setState not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im a noob in React and trying to make a simple app for water phases where the user enters a number and then based on the value it should display the state of water, for example if he enters 212 it should say gas and for 12 it should say solid, but for some reason its not displaying the values correctly, Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            msg: "liquid",
            temp: 0
        };
        this.handlenum1Change = this.handlenum1Change.bind(this);
    }

    handlenum1Change(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.value);
        this.setState({
            temp: Number(evt.target.value)
        });

        let temp = this.state.temp
        if (temp > 100) {
            this.setState({
                msg: "boiling"
            })
        } else if (temp < 32) {
            this.setState({
                msg: "frozen"
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                msg: "liquid"
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> {this.state.msg} </h1>
                <form className="form-inline">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label> Temp: </label>
                        <input type="number"  onChange={this.handlenum1Change} className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When asking for help, please take the time to format your code with reasonable, consistent indentation and without a huge amount of unnecessary whitespace. (It's a good idea when *not* asking for help, too.)

Comment: Thanks for including all of the necessary code in the question. As you can see, I updated the question to make a *runnable version* using 
 Stack Snippets (the toolbar button that looks like `<>` in a page). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) is asynchronous and won't update the state straight away. It collects multiple state changes before updating.
That means, that `this.state` won't hold your new value right away.

Or to quote the React docs here:

> `setState()` does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading `this.state`
>   right after calling `setState()` a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   `componentDidUpdate` or a `setState` callback (`setState(updater,
>   callback)`), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

---

Instead, do it the other way around and work with the user input before setting the new state. That way you can also collectively set both, the temperature and the message at once:

```
const temp = Number(evt.target.value);
let msg = '';
if (temp > 100) {
  msg = 'boiling';
} else if (temp < 32) {
  msg = 'frozen';
} else {
  msg = 'liquid';
}

this.setState({
  temp,
  msg,
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[`setState` is **asynchronous**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous). Separately, if you set state (`setState({msg: ...})`) based on current state (`this.state.temp`), you **must** use the callback version of `setState`.

But in this case you can just set `temp` and `msg` at the same time, since they're both working from something outside of state (the temp from the `input`):

```
handlenum1Change(evt) {
    console.log(evt.target.value);
    const temp = Number(evt.target.value);
    let msg;

    if (temp > 100) {
        msg = "boiling";
    } else if (temp < 32) {
        msg = "frozen";
    } else {
        msg = "liquid";
    }
    this.setState({temp, msg});
}
```

```js
class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            msg: "liquid",
            temp: 0
        };
        this.handlenum1Change = this.handlenum1Change.bind(this);
    }

    handlenum1Change(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.value);
        const temp = Number(evt.target.value);
        let msg;

        if (temp > 100) {
            msg = "boiling";
        } else if (temp < 32) {
            msg = "frozen";
        } else {
            msg = "liquid";
        }
        this.setState({temp, msg});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1> {this.state.msg} </h1>
                <form className="form-inline">
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <label> Temp: </label>
                        <input type="number"  onChange={this.handlenum1Change} className="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is not an **imperative** method to change the state immediately but a **request** you make to React to change the state of your component as soon as it can (see [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)).

Another important thing you should factor in is that the `event` React uses is not a standard HTML Event but rather a `SyntheticEvent` created by React itself to wrap the standard event, and this `SyntheticEvent` will be discarded as soon as possible for "performance reasons".

Now, your problem is easily solved by changing

```
const temp = this.state.temp
```

To

```
const temp = Number(evt.target.value)
```

but you should keep in mind the two above factors when using a React Component's state.

Edit: The consideration about `SyntethicEvent`s is especially important when using the callback version of `setState`, since accessing the value from within that callback will most likely **not** contain the value of the input that fired the `onChange` event, so you have to store it in a variable in the scope outside the callback, for example:

```
handleInputChange = (event) => {
     const value = event.target.value

     this.setState(prevState => {
          return { myValue: prevState.value + value }
     })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[image]  [image]
[image]Since you are not using this.state.temp anywhere else except comparing, you can assign the value in a variable and compare it. FYI, setState wont reflect the changes immediately.

```
handlenum1Change(evt) {
        let temp = evt.target.value;
        if (temp > 100) {
            this.setState({
                msg: "boiling"
            })
        } else if (temp < 32) {
            this.setState({
                msg: "frozen"
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                msg: "liquid"
            })
        }
    }
```